# Route concern and polymorphic model: how to share controller and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Given the routes:

```
Example::Application.routes.draw do
  concern :commentable do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :articles, concerns: :commentable

  resources :forums do
    resources :forum_topics, concerns: :commentable
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

When I edit or add a comment, I need to go back to the "commentable" object. I have the following issues, though:

1) The `redirect_to` in the `comments_controller.rb` would be different depending on the parent object

2) The references on the views would differ as well

```
= simple_form_for comment do |form|
```

Is there a practical way to share views and controllers for this `comment` resource?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the parent in a before filter like this:

**comments_controller.rb**

```
before_filter: find_parent

def find_parent
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      @parent = $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can redirect or do whatever you please depending on the parent type.

For example in a view:

```
= simple_form_for [@parent, comment] do |form|
```

Or in a controller

**comments_controller.rb**

```
redirect_to @parent # redirect to the show page of the commentable.
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I'll give it a go although I could have more than one parent. For example I'll need `simple_form_for [forum, forum_topic, comment]`; or `redirect_to [forum, forum_topic]`. I'll play with splats and see where it gets me.

Comment: @amencarini You could still do Arjan a favour and accept his answer!

Answer (score 19):

In Rails 4 you can pass options to concerns.  So if you do this:

```
# routes.rb
concern :commentable do |options|
  resources :comments, options
end


resources :articles do
  concerns :commentable, commentable_type: 'Article'
end
```

Then when you `rake routes`, you will see you get a route like

`POST /articles/:id/comments, {commentable_type: 'Article'}`

That will override anything the request tries to set to keep it secure.  Then in your CommentsController:

```
# comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_commentable, only: [:index, :create]

  def create
    @comment = Comment.create!(commentable: @commentable)
    respond_with @comment
  end

  private
  def set_commentable
    commentable_id = params["#{params[:commentable_type].underscore}_id"]
    @commentable = params[:commentable_type].constantize.find(commentable_id)
  end

end
```

One way to test such a controller with rspec is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CommentsController do

  let(:article) { create(:article) }

  [:article].each do |commentable|

    it "creates comments for #{commentable.to_s.pluralize} " do
      obj = send(commentable)
      options = {}
      options["#{commentable.to_s}_id"] = obj.id
      options["commentable_type".to_sym] = commentable.to_s.camelize
      options[:comment] = attributes_for(:comment)
      post :create, options
      expect(obj.comments).to eq [Comment.all.last]
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was very helpful! Unfortunately I've found a mistake — in routes.rb you have to use a concern using 'concerns' method, like this: "concerns :commentable, commentable_type: 'Article'".