# Routing concerns defining different param for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Recently I got to know about rails concerns in routes from this discussion
[How to have one resource in routes for namespace and root path altogether - Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725697/how-to-have-same-routes-with-and-without-namespace-rails-4). Now in my application I have routes like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :photos
  resources :businesses
  resources :projects
  resources :quotes
end
resources :photos, param: 'slug'
resources :businesses, param: 'slug' do
  resources :projects, param: 'slug' #As I need both the url one inside business and one outside
end
resources :projects, param: 'slug'
resources :quotes, param: 'slug'
```

And there are many more resources which are repeating as I needed them. I know about concerns how to implement them. With the concerns I can do it like this:

```
concern :shared_resources do
  resources :photos
  resources :businesses
  resources :projects
  resources :quotes
end
namespace :admin do
  concerns :shared_resources
end
concerns :shared_resources
```

but how can I give different `param` each time in the concerns? I tried doing it like this:

```
concerns :shared_resources, param: 'slug'
```

But this brings no change in the routes. And if I add:

```
resources :photos, param: 'slug'
```

Then it will add to both the routes slug instead of id. But in admin side I need id and in front end I need slug. So are there any options to pass this in the concerns so to DRY up the code.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I remembered seeing something about this. It wasn't in the Rails guide, but [an answer to a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466320/2832282) that kinda surprised me. You can use a block : (quoted from the aforementionned answer)

> In Rails 4 you can pass options to concerns. So if you do this:

```
# routes.rb
concern :commentable do |options|
  resources :comments, options
end

resources :articles do
  concerns :commentable, commentable_param: 'slug'
end
```

> Then when you rake routes, you will see you get a route like

```
POST /articles/:id/comments, {commentable_param: 'slug'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately this didn't work I didn't find any changes. Have you ever tried this? Means if this worked for you.

Comment: Hmm I wasn't sure of this, but in the question I linked they have used parameters that looked like `${concern_name}_something`. Can you try with this syntax if it works ? To be honest I didn't try it myself but given the upvotes of the answer I thought it'd work...